# IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a random "We're sorry, but something went wrong" when I start the rails server and a `IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address` error in the terminal.  Most of the time Ill get the error, but sometimes it will actually work for a few minutes and then show up. No idea what the issue could be.

Edit: Ok now im gettign a completely new error after restart my computer.

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
):
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
  /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
  /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
  /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
  /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (77.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (85.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/David/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (179.1ms)
```

Comment: can you post complete error stack here?

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka added.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your Postgres Server is not running

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

You need to start your server and all will work well.